# LAPACKE matrix inversion segmentation fault C

Tags: c, segmentation-fault, lapack, lapacke

I am trying to write a code using lapacke libraries to invert a complex matrix in C. However I am stuck with a segmentation fault which seems to depend on the size N of the matrix. What's more is that the size for which the segmentation fault happens varies each time I compile the program or I touch anything. This makes me think that somewhere the code is trying to access badly allocated or forbidden memory. Unfortunately, I dont' understand how this happens since it seems to be related with the LAPACKE functions themeselves. In fact, when the function /`*MatrixComplexInv(invA,A,N);*/` (  in which the LAPACKE functions are called for the inversion) is commented the segmentation fault *doesn't* happen. 
Below there is the *working* code that can be compiled and run on its own.

```
 #include <stdio.h>
#include <lapacke.h>
#include <complex.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>

void  Ctranspose( double complex *, double complex * ,int );
void MatrixComplexInv(double complex *, double complex *, int );


int main(int argc,  const char * * argv) {


 int  i,j,k,N = 4;/*if N> bigger than a small number 4,6,7.. it gives segmentation fault*/

double complex *A = calloc(N*N,sizeof(double complex)),
               *b = calloc(N*N,sizeof(double complex)),
               *Ap =calloc(N*N,sizeof(double complex));


    double complex *invA =calloc(N*N,sizeof(double complex));


        for(i=0;i<N;i++){
            for(j=0;j<N;j++){ 

            A[i*N+j] = 1+sin(i*j)*i+I*j;    
            Ap[i*N+j] = 1+sin(i*j)*i+I*j;   
            }
          }

    /*Segmentation fault in this function, due to 
     * 
    LAPACKE_zgetrf(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR, n, n, tempA , n,&n);


    LAPACKE_zgetri(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR, n, tempA , n, &n );
    * 
    * both.
    */
    MatrixComplexInv(invA,A,N);


    for(i=0;i<N;i++){
     for(j=0;j<N;j++){ 
         for(k = 0;k<N;k++){
            b[i*N+j]+=invA[i*N + k]*Ap[k*N + j];
         }


   printf("(%lf,%lf)\t", creal(b[i*N + j]),cimag(b[i*N + j]));/*tests that the result produces the inverse matrix A^{-1}A = 1*/


    }
     printf("\n");
    }

      return 0;
    }   


    void Ctranspose( double complex *Transposed, double complex *M ,int n)
    {

    int i,j;
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)

    for(j=0;j<n;j++) Transposed[i+n*j] = M[i*n+j];
    }


    void MatrixComplexInv(double complex *invA, double complex *A, int n)
    {

    double complex *tempA = (double complex*) malloc( n*n*sizeof(double complex) );


     Ctranspose(tempA,A,n);

    /*SEGMENTATION HAPPEN IN THESE TWO FUNCTIONS*/
    LAPACKE_zgetrf(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR, n, n, tempA , n,&n);


    LAPACKE_zgetri(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR, n, tempA , n, &n );


     Ctranspose(invA,tempA,n);


     free(tempA);

    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the correction, however this doesn't affect the outcome.

Comment: yeah this was a quick test program and the printf was sloppy. However the segmentation fault stands regardless.

Comment: Why are you allocating memory with `malloc` but freeing it with `LAPACKE_free`?

Comment: Where exactly does the segfault happen? What's the stack trace?

Comment: I have edited the question. The segmentation fault happens in both lapacke functions. The error message on terminal is simply Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: And the stack trace?

Comment: ./test() [0x400ae5]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf0) [0x7f94dbe9e830]
./test() [0x400949]
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Comment: is this what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `LAPACKE_zgetrf(LAPACK_ROW_MAJOR, n, n, tempA , n,&n);`, the last argument of [LAPACKE_zgetrf](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-html/d1/d56/lapacke__zgetrf_8c_a9ec730a8654106933ca22548c93afdcd.html) points to n, a single integer. On the contrary, the argument `ipiv` should be [a pointer to an array of integer of dimension max(m,n), to store pivot indices](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/explore-3.1.1-html/zgetrf.f.html) This could explain a segmentation fault.

The `ipiv` computed by `LAPACKE_zgetrf()` must also be provided to `LAPACKE_zgetri()` as input, to get the correct inverse matrix.

Comment: I wish I could pay you a beer.